# Pickle dump-load appears to modify numpy data

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I expected that a pickle write-read would return a duplicate of the input data. This block of code seems to contradict my expectation:

```
import pickle
import filecmp
import numpy as np


def pload(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


def pdump(data, filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)


v1 = np.ndarray([1, 2])

v2 = np.float64(1.2)

for v in [(v1,), (v2,), (v1, v2)]:
    pdump(v, "/tmp/test-a")
    tmp = pload("/tmp/test-a")
    numpy_eq = all([np.array_equal(a, b) for a, b in zip(v, tmp)])
    pdump(tmp, "/tmp/test-b")
    pickle_eq = filecmp.cmp("/tmp/test-a", "/tmp/test-b")
    print(f"Equality: numpy={numpy_eq}, pickle={pickle_eq}")
```

This script outputs:

```
Equality: numpy=True, pickle=True
Equality: numpy=True, pickle=True
Equality: numpy=True, pickle=False
```

I expected to see all True; the last line shows *pickle=False*. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You shouldn't be using: `np.ndarray([1, 2])`.  `np.array([1,2])` is the correct way to make a 2 element integer array.   Making `np.float64(1.2)` also isn't 'proper' `numpy`; it works, but not very useful.  That said. I'm not sure what the `filecmp` is proving.  I can't reproduce your results with `dumps/loads`.  And when checking from changes if any, I prefer to check `type`, `dtype` and `shape` (where applicable).

Comment: Thanks. This is a minimal example that demonstrates the behavior that puzzles me. In my original script, the ndarray and float64 come from numpy workflows.

Comment: Even though the files differ (in size at least) in the case of the tuple of floats, the arrays, when reloaded still match.  Also the files do match when `v1` is `int` dtype.